# What permission is necessary to see the Template Unique Name (DeveloperName of email templates)

Tags: email-template

What permission on a users' profile is necessary so that the user can see not only the Email Template Name, but also the **Template Unique Name** of email templates in the setup GUI? The permission "Manage Public Templates" is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user will need:

"Customize Application" permission